# Mapbox - add source and layers via GL JS vs Mapbox studio

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

1. Are there any differences between:

**a)** Displaying map with custom style created in Mapbox Studio with some custom tileset (created and uploaded in Studio) as layer.

vs

**b)** Displaying map with some style (without created data),then add programatically source and layer.

Maybe some some caching is happening while option **a** ?

2. What should be faster to display when user inits **a** map a or **b**  ? What is optimal when considering network usage ?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic thing to consider here is that the mapbox tileset layer is of tileset format which means that it will load with the map tiles when the map loads and as the user interacts with the map forcing more data to be downloaded.

The most common way to implement option (b) would be to add the data on load. This is oversimplifying it, but this basically means that your data layer is going to update after your map tiles update. Depending on connection speed the user may or may not notice this.

I'm not quite sure on network usage, but it would be perceived faster by the end user to use a tileset.

Note: [There are charges associated using mapbox tileservice](https://www.mapbox.com/mts) which may or may not be something to consider based on your use case.